# Trigger To delete Old Records from active table and Insert to history table

Tags: sql, sql-server

**sql server 2008**

May anyone share their expertise how to achieve the below scenario

I have two table. active and history both have same structure.

What I am trying to achieve, whenever new record insert to active table, whatever
records existing in active table move to history.

I am trying to hold only current active records

I have a column called fetch date and if any record have fetch date not same 
as getdate must be moved to history table. those record should not present
in Active table.

Thanks

Comment: fetch date may not necessary equal to getdate at the point of insert. Maybe you can post some samples and expected result

Comment: what is your intention actually ? Are you looking for a way to get the lastest record in a table ?

Comment: @Squirrel :only wants to hold record from the last load in active table. remaining all 
records in historical table

Comment: staging table ? why not just 1) insert into history select from active 2) truncate active table

Comment: @Squirrel: Kindly elaborate..

Comment: before loading the data to active table, insert whatever records in active to history then delete the active table then load the fresh data. Will this work for you ?

Comment: @Squirrel: Thanks a lot: this is exactly what i am looking for. but how can i automate it. please suggest.

Comment: create a stored procedure to do that

Comment: @Squirrel: Thanks......

Comment: @Squirrel: I tried something like this. but not sure will it work. CREATE proc BACKUP_TB 
tbname AS varchar(MAX) 
AS 
BEGIN
SET nocount ON; 
DECLARE query AS varchar(MAX)
SET query = 'select * into '+tbname+'_backup from '+tbname+''; 
EXEC (query)
SET nocount OFF; 
END

Answer (score 0):

you have several syntax error there.

I am merely correcting the syntax

```
CREATE PROCEDURE BACKUP_TB 
    @tbname varchar(MAX) 
AS 
 BEGIN 
    SET nocount ON; 
    DECLARE @query varchar(MAX) 
    SET @query = 'select * into '+ @tbname + '_backup from ' + @tbname + ''; 
    EXEC (@query) 
    SET nocount OFF; 
END
```

few issues you should take note

1. `SELECT INTO <table name>` will create new table and insert the result. It will only works once. Then second time you run it, it will give error as the target table already existed. You should use pre-create all necessary tables and use `insert into backup_table ( <column list> ) select <column list> from original_table`
2. Avoid using `SELECT *`, it is best practice to specify the column name explicitly
3. If you have to use Dynamic SQL, do read up more about it. Example : [The Curse and Blessings of Dynamic SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html). And take note of possible SQL Injection attack.

Comment: Thanks a lot squirrel